# Python not finding None in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Today python stopped finding None in a numpy array. My code breaks because of the following. Any clue appreciated.

```
In [36]: abc = np.array([3,2,None])

In [37]: None is abc[-1]
Out[37]: True

In [38]: None in abc
/Users/py/htrans.py:1: FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an    elementwise object comparison in the future. #!/usr/bin/env python3
Out[38]: False

In [39]: abc==None
/Users/py/htrans.py:1: FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future. #!/usr/bin/env python3
Out[39]: False

sys.platform
Out[42]: 'darwin'

sys.version
Out[43]: '3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:24:55) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]'

np.version.version
Out[44]: '1.10.4'
```

Comment: What does `type(None)` show and what does `None is seq[wave:wave+lead][-1]` show?

Comment: `ipdb> type(None)`

`<class 'NoneType'>`


`ipdb> None is seq[wave:wave+lead]`

`False`

ipdb>

Comment: Did you include the `[-1]` there?

Comment: `ipdb> None is seq[wave:wave+lead][-1]
True`

Comment: Curious... and what does `seq[wave:wave_lead] == None` give?

Comment: sorry: I will post more info in the question above

Comment: done see above ..

Comment: This is very strange.  Please add `sys.platform, sys.version, np.version.version`.

Comment: numpy does look oldish

Comment: You're using something like `numpy 1.9`, there was an issue with this comparison around then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/1608

According to the link, this bug was reported and fixed in the 1.13.0 release of Numpy.

A quick workaround you can use is:

`any(elem is None for elem in abc)`